# How to count and sum elements in a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, count, sum

i have a array that returns some numbers. and i want to add those numbers together and also count them.

here is what i have so far:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/215844978437619/reviews');
$parsed = json_decode($homepage,true);
foreach ($parsed['data'] as $key => $values){
$totalRatings1 = $values['rating'] ;
}
?>
```

what i am trying to do is to sum the `$values['rating']` together and also count them.

So that: `$totalRatings = sum_array($values['rating'])` and `$totalCount = count($values['rating'])`

but i get lost in the sintax.

any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What does `but i get lost in the sintax.` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/215844978437619/reviews');
$parsed = json_decode($homepage,true);

$totalRatings = 0;
$totalRated = 0;

foreach ($parsed['data'] as $key => $values){
   $totalRatings += (int) $values['rating'];
   $totalRated++;
}
?>
```

`$totalRatings` will have the aggregated sum of all ratings, `$totalRated` will be the count of how many ratings there are.

Answer (score 2):

Just declare two variables and then increment them on each iteration:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/215844978437619/reviews');
$parsed = json_decode($homepage,true);

$totalRating = 0;
$totalItems = 0;
foreach ($parsed['data'] as $key => $values) {
    $totalRating += $values['rating'];
    $totalItems++;
}
```

`$totalRating` will hold the sum of all rating while `$totalItems` will contain the total number of items.